# How Do I Add and Delete an Array in a Nested Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Nested Reactive Form Array that I need to duplicate.  For some reason, I'm only. able to duplicate one part of the array. Here is a link to the code. I've updated the code to include a cascading dropdown I did with ngModel.  It seems when I add another array my selection changes with my second one. I know it's something to do with my model I just can't figure it out. I've updated the StackBlitz link below.  thanks.

```
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
})
export class App {
  selectedCategoryList: String = "--Choose Category--";

    categoryList: Array<any> = [
    {
        name: "Test One",
        subCategoryList: [
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 1"
            },
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 1.1"
            },
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 2.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Test Two",
        subCategoryList: [
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 2"
            },
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 2.1"
            },
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 2.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Test Three",
        subCategoryList: [
            {
                typeList: [
                    ""
                ],
                name: "Test 3"
            }
        ]
    }
];

selectedCountry: String = "--Choose Document Category--";

subCategoryList: Array<any> = [];
typeList: Array<any> = [];

  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  documentForm = this.fb.group({
    appCode: ['123'],
    accountType: [''],
    emailId: ['test@aol.com'],
    IDV: [''],
    envelopeRequest: this.fb.group({
      documents: this.fb.array([]),
    }),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.form = this.fb.group({
    //   documents: this.fb.array([]),
    // });
    this.initDocument();
  }

  changeCategoryList(category: any) {
    this.subCategoryList = this.categoryList.find((cat: any) => cat.name == category.target.value).subCategoryList;
  }
  
  changeSubCategoryList(subList: any) {
    this.typeList = this.categoryList.find((cat: any) => cat.name == this.selectedCountry).subCategoryList.find((stat: any) => stat.name == subList.target.value).typeList;
  }

  initDocument() {
    this.documents.push(this.newDocument());
    let documentIndex = this.documents.length - 1;
    this.newDocumentFieldGroup(documentIndex);

    //console.log(this.documentFields(0).controls.length);
  }

  newDocument() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      documentId: new FormControl(''),
      documentFields: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  newDocumentFieldGroup(comIndex: number) {
    this.documentFields(comIndex).push(this.newDocumentFields());

    this.documentFields(comIndex).push(
      this.newDocumentFields('documentSubCategory')
    );
  }

  newDocumentFields(name = 'documentCategory') {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(name),
      value: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  get documents() {
    // Problem was from here, should use `documentForm` --> envelopeRequest --> documents
    return this.documentForm.controls.envelopeRequest.controls
      .documents as FormArray;
  }

  documentFields(comIndex: number) {
    return this.documents.controls[`${comIndex}`].get(
      'documentFields'
    ) as FormArray;
  }

  documentFieldsIndexes(comIndex: number) {
    return Array(this.documentFields(comIndex).controls.length / 2)
      .fill(0)
      .map((x, i) => i * 2);
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.documentForm.value);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="documentForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  
  <ng-container formGroupName="envelopeRequest">
    <button (click)='initDocument()'>Add Document</button>
    <ng-container formArrayName="documents">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="let control of documents.controls; let comIndex=index"
      >
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="comIndex">
          <div class="row justify-content-start mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              {{comIndex}}
              <input
                type="hidden"
                id="fname"
                name="fname"
                formControlName="documentId"
              />
              <label for="formFile" class="col-form-label">File:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="file"
                id="file"
                name="file"
                formControlName="name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-container formArrayName="documentFields">
            <ng-container
              *ngFor="let skillIndex of documentFieldsIndexes(comIndex);"
            >
              <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Category:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
                    <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value" [(ngModel)]= "selectedCategoryList" (change)="changeCategoryList($event)">
                      <option selected>Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let c of categoryList">
                        {{c.name}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>

                <label class="col-auto col-form-label">Sub-Category:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex + 1">
                    <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value" (change)="changeSubCategoryList($event)">
                      <option selected>Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let s of subCategoryList">{{s.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<pre>{{this.documentForm.value | json }}
```

[Nested Form Array](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jiskqe?file=src%2Fmain.html)

You will see only the input file works but my other fields only repeat in the wrong spot.  Any help will do.  thanks

Comment: Note: Please do share the minimal code to reproduce the issue as code snippet instead of just in link. Refer: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the below code in the `initDocument` method:

```
this.newDocumentFieldGroup(0);
```

which will add the new nested `FormGroup`s into the `documentFields` `FormArray` for the first element of `documents` `FormArray`.

You have to provide the latest index for the `FormGroup` in the `documents` `FormArray`. Do remember that the array index starts from 0.

```
initDocument() {
  this.documents.push(this.newDocument());
  let documentIndex = this.documents.length - 1;
  this.newDocumentFieldGroup(documentIndex);

  //console.log(this.documentFields(0).controls.length);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvz5x1?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

---

**Updated:**

The reason why all the categories were updated to the same value as you are using `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value" [(ngModel)]= "selectedCategoryList" (change)="changeCategoryList($event)">
```

This results that all the form controls will share the same value. Remove the `[(ngModel)]` as it is not needed and you are using the Reactive Form.

```
<select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value"  (change)="changeCategoryList($event)">
  ...
</select>
```

If you are keen to set the default value at the beginning, would suggest using the `patchValue` method.

```
newDocumentFields(name = 'documentCategory') {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl(name),
    value: new FormControl(
      name == 'documentCategory' ? '--Choose Document Category--' : ''
    ),
  });
}
```

[Demo (for updated question) @  StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hmgshg?file=src%2Fmain.html)

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll make sure I add my sample code as well to the thread.  Your Demo works within StackBlitz, thank you.  When I try to add it to my project I run into an issue where if I select an option that option selection changes for other options.  Here is a link to a screenshot of what I mean. [link](https://pasteboard.co/Q9UEBHfRn6UK.jpg)  @YongShun

Comment: Hi @fearless924, updated answer based on your updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @YongShun.  I'm assuming that the Sub-Category select option, to not the same, I would need to create a new method as well

Comment: Please! This is not the way to ask the question. Provide the actual issue that you face, write it in the question. If it is a new issue/problem, create another question post. This is the third time for this question that you ask which each issue is different. The answer written is designed to solve the problem stated in the question. Stack Overflow is not the place that asks people to help you write the code.

Comment: Thanks @YongShon for your help.  I will write another question.